# NightwatchJS can't locate 2nd element out of list of elements

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to find a list of product images then locate the 2nd product image to click on it, but nightwatch can't find it. The page is https://www.artsyjewels.com/collections/earrings
Can someone advise me how to click on this? Thanks.

```
xpathproduct: (.//div[@class="yit-wcan-container"]//following-sibling::div[@class="jas-product-image pr oh jas-product-image-equal"])[2]

NightwatchJS can't find the element
.waitForElementVisible('xpath', '@xpathproduct', 1000)
```

Alternatively I can use CSS selector :nth-of-type(2) and it works, but wondering how to get it to work with above xpath

```
div.jas-grid-item.jas-col-md-3.jas-col-sm-4.jas-col-xs-6.mt__30.product.has-post-thumbnail.user_custom:nth-of-type(2)>div>div.jas-product-image.pr.oh.jas-product-image-equal>a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Element Properties](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/working-with-page-objects/#element-properties) section of the Nightwatch.js documentation, you can either define an index on your page object to get the second instance of an element matching your selector, or do something like

```
.waitForElementVisible({ selector: '@xpathproduct', index: 1 }, 1000)
```

to change the index at call time.

Note: I think the documentation is incorrect about the index to pass to get the second element; in my experience, `index: 0` gets the first element, so `index: 1` is what you want to get the second one.